# Importing users to Buddypress with custom fields

Tags: custom-field, mysql, buddypress, import, bulk-import

Here's the setup:

- The client uses a proprietary
  custom-coded PHP CMS and is wanting
  to move to WordPress with BuddyPress.
- The old, custom CMS has a roster
  functionality, which I'm using
  BuddyPress custom fields to replace.
- The custom fields are basic contact
  info (Phone, Fax) and company info
  (Text field).

What is the best way to import these? It seems my two options are:

1. Create a pretty large SQL query that
   reformats this data between
   databases (I'm about 3 hours into
   doing it this way so far)
2. Export it into some sort of JSON
   format and use the Ning importer.

If the best option is using the Ning importer, know where I can get an example Ning user list CSV so I may format the user data accordingly? If the best option is using a big MySQL query, what are some things I should look at in terms of row values WordPress expects?

Many thanks!

Comment: Also, if anybody knows of a better way to denote users as belonging to a company than simply a text field (And less involved than renaming the Groups functionality of BuddyPress), that'd be rad too. :)

Comment: Are the buddypress custom fields within WP core? Or do they live in a separate table?

Comment: They're BuddyPress xprofile fields, residing in wp_bp_xprofile_data

Comment: I have created a plugin named BuddyPress Members Import http://www.youngtechleads.com/buddypress-members-import/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a bunch of MySQL statements. My process went:

1. Add users into wp_users.
2. Add first name into wp_usermeta.
3. Add last name into wp_usermeta.
4. Add nickname into wp_usermeta.
5. Add last activity into wp_usermeta. (This is important for BuddyPress; otherwise, users won't show up in the members-loop)
6. Add name to BuddyPress.
7. Add custom "phone" field to BP.
8. Add custom "fax" field to BP.
9. Add custom "company" field to BP.

<strike>If anybody doing something similar comes across this question and would like the SQL I used, feel free to message me.</strike> After half a dozen people requested the SQL code I have, I've written a blog post that includes the full SQL I used, plus a basic importer script. See: http://aendrew.com/content/importing-proprietary-user-database-buddypress-boss